# Rails, Mongrel and deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated

When I do script/server I don't seem to get any deprecation warnings. I know that I should at least be getting one about {{word}} in I18N. Can anyone point out where I can find them? Or how I can enable the deprecation warnings?

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

It's in your locale file. in config/local directory.

Comment: No - I mean the deprecation warnings - I want to see what is deprecated in my code :-)